# Dynamic orderBy Breaks ng-repeat in view in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-service, angularjs-orderby

I am having a problem dynamically ordering my data which I am getting through a service in my controller.  The data loads just fine when I do an initial search, but as soon as I try to update orderBy, all of the data in my views disappear instead of being reordered.  The data I am displaying in my view is the data stored to $scope.filtered_events. Also, my controller is attached via the router to the template.

**Search Controller**

```
(function () {
    .controller("Search", function ($scope, zipcodeSvc, $filter, $http) {

        $scope.$on("search", search);
        $scope.sortBy = "date";

        function search(evt, data) {
            $scope.zip_codes = [];
            $scope.locations = null;
            $scope.response = null;
            $scope.events = null;

            zipcodeSvc.find(data.str, data.dist)
                .then(
                    function (response) {
                        $scope.locations = response;
                        for(i=0; i<$scope.locations.zip_codes.length; i++){
                          $scope.zip_codes.push($scope.locations.zip_codes[i].zip_code);
                        }
                        console.log($scope.zip_codes);


                        $http.get("api/events")
                        .success(function(response){
                          $scope.events = response;
                         //what I want to be able to dynamically order
                          $scope.filtered_events = $filter('eventsInRange')($scope.events, $scope.zip_codes);
                        });
                    },
                    function (err) {
                        console.log("error finding cities: ", err);
                    }
                )

        }
    })
    .filter("eventsInRange", function () {
      return function(events, zipcodes) {
        events_in_range = [];
        for(i=0;i < events.length; i++){
          if(zipcodes.indexOf(events[i].location.zip_code) > -1){
            events_in_range.push(events[i])
          }
        }
        return events_in_range;
      }
    });
}());
```

**Template**

```
<div class="container">
 <p class="bigger">Filter:</p>
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li><a href='#' ng-click="sortBy = 'type'">Cya</a></li>
  <li><a href='#' ng-click="sortBy = 'location.name'">Location</a></li>
  <li><a href='#' ng-click="sortBy = 'date'">Date</a></li>
  <li><a href='#' ng-click="sortBy = 'created_by'">Creator</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="row">
  <div ng-repeat="cya in filtered_events | filter:cyaFilter | orderBy:sortBy" class="col-sm-4 text-center">
    <h2 class="primary"> {{ cya.type }} </h2>
    <div class="well cyas">
      <p> <span class="cya-label primary">Creator:</span> {{cya.created_by}}</p>
      <img class="img-responsive cya-pic" src="http://fpoimg.com/150x150" alt="{{cya.location}} picture">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6"><p> <span class="cya-label primary text-left">Date:</span><br> {{ cya.date }} </p></div>
      <div class="col-sm-6"><p> <span class="cya-label primary text-left">Time:</span><br> {{ cya.time }} </p></div>
    </div>
    <p> <span class="cya-label primary">Location:</span><br />
      {{cya.location.name }} <br />
      {{ cya.location.address }}
      <br /> {{ cya.location.city }}, {{ cya.location.state }}  {{ cya.location.zip_code }}</p>
    <button class="btn btn-primary join" ng-show="false">Join</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**Zip code Service**

```
(function () {
    angular.module("app.data")
        .factory("zipcodeSvc", function ($http, $q) {
            return {
                find: findByLocation
            }

            function findByLocation(location, distance) {

                var url = "api/zipcodes?location=" + location + "&distance=" + distance;

                var defer = $q.defer();

                $http.get(url)
                    .success(function (response) {
                        defer.resolve(response);
                    })
                    .error(function (err) {
                        defer.reject(err);
                        console.log(err);
                    })
                return defer.promise;
            }
        });
}());
```

EDIT - added the data structure of `$scope.filtered_events`:

```
[
  { date: "mm/dd/yyyy", 
    location: { 
       address: "Someplace", 
       city: "Some city", 
       zip_code: "12345", 
       name: "Some Name", 
       state: "Some State"
     }, 
     time: "hh:mm AM", 
     type: "Some type", 
     created_by: "Some person" 
  }, 
  //etc
]
```

Comment: Please show how the array `filtered_events` looks like - in questions like these it is more important than seeing how you are getting it. Would it also not filter if you were to hardcode the data?

Comment: `[
    {
        "date": "mm/dd/yyyy",
        "location": {
            "address": "Someplace",
            "city": "Some city",
            "zip_code": "12345",
            "name": "Some Name",
            "state": "Some State"
        },
        "time": "hh:mm AM",
        "type": "Some type",
        "created_by": "Some person"
    },
    etc. etc. etc.
]`

Comment: The information works if I pipe it directly in outside of the service into a variable in the controller but once I moved everything into a function to use the service to grab the data the orderBy methods I was using caused the page to blank out.  If I set the filter inside of the success call `$filter('orderBy')($scope.filtered_events, 'type')` it will correctly do the orderBy when it first loads.

Comment: It works for me with an async data: http://plnkr.co/edit/P348x6FIQuBDgf2sledx?p=preview. I removed, however, the `cyaFilter` since it's not defined - and could be the thing that is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is your `orderBy` filter is not updating your `$scope.filtered_events` binding. The reason everything works correctly when you add `$filter('orderBy')($scope.filtered_events, 'type')` directly in the `success` callback is because `$scope.$apply()` is being called for you implicitly.

To fix this add `$scope.$apply()` at the end of your `orderBy` function.

See [this](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html) for a quick explanation.

Comment: Right now in the code I am updating the `orderBy` filter by changing the variable I am ordering by in the view `sortBy` in a `ng-click`.  So I'm not using a function in the filter.  I am just swapping a variable here `<div ng-repeat="cya in filtered_events | filter:cyaFilter | orderBy:sortBy" class="col-sm-4 text-center">`  which is set initially in the controller but changed with on click, for example here `<li><a href='#' ng-click="sortBy = 'type'">Cya</a></li>` So I am unclear as to where I would add $scope.$apply().